# Rails 6 - change params for root_path in URL to SEO friendly URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

I know how to change routes when I'm calling some controller which name is in URL, but do not have idea what do with this:

Will_paginate:

```
http://localhost:3000/?page=4
```

and I want

```
http://localhost:3000/page/4
```

Route:

```
root to: 'pages#home_logged_in'
```

Comment: Is `get '/pages/:page' => 'pages#home_logged_in'` enough?

Comment: enought ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `will_paginate` has the functionality to change the way it structures the links so you may need to calculate and display the page links manually in your views.

In the routes, you can setup a standard non-paginated route to handle the initial request and then a paginated route to handle individual pages.

```
get '/pages/:page', to: 'pages#index' # will pass params[:page]
root to: 'pages#index'
```

Then in the `pages#index` you just check for and apply the `page` param if it exists:

```
def index
  page = params[:page] || 1
  @items_being_paginated = ItemModel.paginate(page)
end
```

I've not used the `will_paginate` gem personally so the gem specific code is taken from their [wiki](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki).

---

Depending on what you're using this for -- if its just paginating items, for example -- the above should work for you. If you're trying to get SEO quality links for individual items you can using dynamic routing, like this:

```
  get '*path', to: 'pages#show', as: 'pages_show'
```

or parameterized

```
  get ':category/:sub_category', to: 'pages#index', as: 'sub_pages_index'
  get ':category/:sub_category/pages/:page', to: 'pages#index', as: 'sub_paginated_pages_index'
  get ':category/:sub_category/:item', to: 'pages#show', as: 'pages_show'
```

In the controller you just parse the route with the first, or use the params with the second.

[This part](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) of the Rails Routing Guide might interest you if you want more info.